# How to analyze a latin square design in IBM SPSS?

Tags: spss, latin-square

I conducted an experiment with a latin square design.

[image]

How do I arrange the data in IBM SPSS to analyze it in one file? I've watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APvlPjYSSaI, where groups (e.g., Block 1 = Group 1, Block 2 = Group 2, Block 3 = Group 3) have been built in addition to the time period of measurement. But in the example of the video, the order of the treatments are the same (and not arranged in a latin square as in my example). So how should I arrange the data from the latin square design in SPSS?

This is a within subject design, as I measure after each treatment my dependent variable (3 times measurement of dependent variable per subject). Each Block contains 5 subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### latin squares

Latin squares are usually used to balance the possible treatments in an experiment, and to prevent confounding the results with the order of treatment.
There is no special way to analyze the latin square. You just make a note of it when describing your methods.

### arranging data for analysis

From your description, this is a between within design. Each subject was measured 3 times, and subjects are grouped by the order of treatments.
Your data should be arranged like so for ANOVA:
[image: screenshot of data table]

---

I believe this thread would be useful for you:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244636/evaluating-contrasts-in-repeated-measures-anova-spss

Comment: Thanks in advance for your answer
- Yes I want to analyze the order of the treatments as factor
- There are 3 Measurements of the Subject on 3 Time periods
- It is a within subject design, but I thought it is also a within --> as I have 3 Blocks with changing treatments orders?

Comment: I've also added an advanced picture in my question to outline the design better

Comment: Edited my answer. especially note the link at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your response. To clearify, by order group A you mean the order of treatments right? So order group A = A,B,C. Order group B = B,C,A, and order group C = C,A,B. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Please allow me one last question. Before I arrange the data like outlined in your table, I first have to rearange them in the way, that all measurements following a specific treatment condition (e.g A,B, or C) are in one column right? --> For instance: Lets take Subject 1 and Subject 6 from my table. The have different sequences of the treatments. For subject 1 --> A,B,C and for subject 6 --> B,C,A. This means first have to bring subject 6 data in the sequence A,B,C like for subject one and then add the data to make sure that each conditions measurements are in one column. Correct? - Thanks

Comment: Actually, it depends whether you want the type of treatment or the order of treatment as your main factor. In most cases yopu'd want the type as the main factor and this indeed wasn't clear from my table. I updated my answer to make it clearer.